# How can I get this to loop back to the start if the selection by the user isnt S, D or Y?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do I get this to loop back to the main? I am new to coding like this, mostly just games I code so something like this shouldn't seem too hard but for the life of me I cant get it to loop

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float Age = 0;
        // ask whether age will be in years, days or seconds
        Console.WriteLine("In what format would you like to enter your age? 
        S for Seconds, D for Days, Y for Years. ");
        string choice = Console.ReadLine();
        // get choice
        // if choose seconds
        // get age
        // multiply by the number of seconds in an earth year
            if (choice == "s")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age in seconds");
                string number = Console.ReadLine();
                Age = Convert.ToInt32(number);
            }

            // if choose days
            // get age
            // multiply by the number of seconds in an earth year
            if (choice == "d")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age in days");
                string number = Console.ReadLine();
                Age = Convert.ToInt32(number);
                Age *= 86400;
            }

            // if choose years
            // get age
            // multiply by the number of seconds in an earth year
            if (choice == "y")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age in years");
                string number = Console.ReadLine();
                Age = Convert.ToInt32(number);
                Age *= 86400 * 365.25f;
            }
```

Comment: You can add a boolean variable named 'done', initially set to false, and use this as the control of a while loop that surrounds your prompt and user response checks.  If the user enters valid input, set done to true.  e.g.
`var done = false;
while (!done) {
  /* prompt and check responses; for valid response, set done = true; */
}`

Answer (score 0):

You´d need a loop checking if the input is already correct:

```
bool correct;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("In what format would you like to enter your age? " +
         "S for Seconds, D for Days, Y for Years. ");
    string choice = console.ReadLine();

    if(choice == "y") { ... correct = true; }
    else if (choice == "s")  { ... correct = true; }
    else if (choice == "d")  { ... correct = true; }
    else correct = false;
} while(!correct);
```

The do-while loop ensures the code will execute at least once and stops when the first valid input is given.

Comment: Currently just getting an error on the word correct in
while(!correct);

Comment: @LiamFlanagan And which? I´m not a wizzard who can guess your error, but I´m pretty sure the compiler clearly sais you exactly what the error is.

Comment: @LiamFlanagan First: don´ßt post additional information to your question into an answer, just edit your question appropriately. Second: from my code you´ll see I´ve used `else/else if`-construct to ensure `correct`*will* definilty* get a value. Checking if your `choice` equals `y` and afterwards checking if it equals `d` is non-sense, isn´t it?

Comment: Okay thank you this worked... Now where would I enter a Console.WriteLine statement saying to the user "Sorry that is wrong, please try again"

Comment: Also the " . . . " sections you put in, Is that where I put my question. E.x. "Please enter your age in days, year, seconds or whatever"

Comment: @LiamFlanagan The ... is for the parts within your `if`-statements, e.g. `Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age in seconds");
                string number = Console.ReadLine();
                Age = Convert.ToInt32(number);`